# Choosing SPD for Solar Panel & Inverter

Tags: surge-protection

I have 18 Solar Panels Installed in series
(Maximum open circuit voltage)VOC is  51.8 V
& Operating Current Imp 13.36 A
AND

MPPT Inverter Max PV Voltage   1100       d.c. V
MPPT Voltage Range  140 - 1000 d.c. V
Nominal Input Voltage  580        d.c. V

What should be DC SPD (Surge Protection Devise) maximum continuous operating voltage (Uc) to be USED?